# After downloading an app, "The requested item could not be found on this device" error

Tags: android

When downloading my app from Market, when I tap on the Open button to try to run it, a toaster message says: "The requested item could not be found on this device and so could not be launched." But in fact, it's downloaded alright and its icon shows in app screen, if I tap on the icon, it runs fine. But this message is really annoying and is a turn off for many users.

Does anybody have any idea? Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:** In this app, I have two launcher icons, launching two different activities. Could this be the cause? I mean, when the user clicks the Open button from Market program, which activity would be launch? The first one???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out it's this:

In my app's manifest file, there used to be two launcher activities. That is, two activities with a category like this:

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

This is not a mistake, it was intentional. Two activities launch different functionality of the app. I then changed one of them. I remove its LAUNCHER attribute and use CREATE_SHORTCUT instead:

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.CREATE_SHORTCUT" />
```

Of course there is more to just the above, but the point is: Don't use more than one Launcher activities, or when the user clicks the Open button from Market app, it doesn't know which activity to launch. User Android's Shortcuts facility. (That is, long-press on any empty spot on Home screen, select Shortcuts from the pop-up menu. That's the Shortcuts I meant.)